# SQL Advanced query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to update if exists or insert if not exists but this query won't work for some reason

```
DECLARE @serverID varchar(60)
SET @serverID='(SELECT `c_server` FROM `admin_settings` WHERE `member_id`='%1')'
IF EXISTS (SELECT `id` FROM `s_advanced_info` WHERE `s_id` = @serverID)
UPDATE
    `s_advanced_info`
SET
    `s_hostname`='%2',
    `s_password`='%3',
    `s_admin_password`='%4',
    `s_motd`='%5',
    `s_sigcheck`='%6',
    `s_maxplayers`='%7',
    `s_kickduplicate`='%8',
    `s_sidechat`='%9',
    `s_von`='%10',
    `s_vonquality`='%11',
    `s_datetime_type`='%12',
    `s_static_date`='%13',
    `s_static_time`='%14'
WHERE
    `s_id` = @serverID
ELSE
INSERT INTO
    `s_advanced_info`
VALUES
    ('',@serverID,'%2','%3','%4','%5','%6','%7','%8','%9','%10',
    '%11','%12','%13','%14')
```

When I try it in the mysql console it says that the error is here:

DECLARE @serverID varchar(60)
SET @serverID = '(SELECT `c_server` FROM `admin_settings` WHERE `member_id` = '%1')'

What does the error mean and how to correct it?

Comment: So, whats the question?

Comment: congrats , you know advance queries!!!

Comment: what is it that you want us to do with it...?

Comment: updated sorry i am tired :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: DECLARE @serverID varchar(60) SET @serverID = (SELECT c_server FROM admin_settings WHERE member_id = '%1')

Becasue it seems like you are setting the serverId variable to a string which happens to be a sql-query. Is that really what you want to do?